# Initializing hibernate for use with spring transactions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have created a spring-boot based java application that uses spring's tasks.  This is a console based java application that also uses hibernate to access database.  This application is based on a spring sample for tasks and uses annotations instead of configuration files. For hibernate, I am actually using hibernate.cfg.xml and am initializing the hibernate session factory myself.

I wanted to use Spring's declaration transaction management but they are not working because I have not been able to find sample of how to initialize spring session factory through annotations.  All samples show configuration through a configuration files.  Can anybody point to how to initialize hibernate session factory through spring using annotations and code so that spring's declarative transactions would work.

Thanks in advance.

Waqar

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 public class AppConfig {
 @Bean
 public FooRepository fooRepository() {
     // configure and return a class having @Transactional methods
     return new JdbcFooRepository(dataSource());
 }

 @Bean
 public DataSource dataSource() {
     // configure and return the necessary JDBC DataSource
 }

 @Bean
 public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
     return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
 }
}
```

Comment: for details you can check http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html